# IPTables/VPN forwarding

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, forwarding, pptpd

Goals: 
1) allow VPN users to access internet without any restrictions
2) allow server itself to access internet, but using specified ports only (mail, web, remote access)

Server config:
1) VPN (poptop/postgresql/Cake VPN billing)
2) iptables
3) mail (dovecot/postfix/spamasassin/postgrey), apache, tomcat, vsftpd, ssh
4) Arch Linux

5) 
Internet interface - eth0
Local interface - eth1
VPN virtual interface - ppp0

Problem: I stfwed, rtfmed and created script that performs forwarding with IPTables. It *works* but only for one client from ppp0 interface. First client have full internet connection. But any other clients cannot connect to anything.

Question: How can I expand this script on any number of clients?

Really, I'm not admin, so I'm very sorry for this lame question (and poor english, because I'm russian). But it's very important because now we are working without VPN ;)

TIA

This is my script under /etc/rc.d/router :

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/rc.conf
. /etc/rc.d/functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    stat_busy "Starting Iptables Rules"

    VPN_INTERFACES=( ppp0 )
    lan_interface=eth1
    internet_interface=eth0

    echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    iptables -F
    iptables -F -t nat
    iptables -F -t mangle

    iptables -X
    iptables -t nat -X
    iptables -X -t mangle

    iptables -P INPUT DROP
    iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP

    iptables --append INPUT --protocol 47 --jump ACCEPT
    iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 1723

    # MASKARAD ppc
    iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o $internet_interface -j MASQUERADE

    # traf local lo
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
    # ICMP ping_lan
    iptables -A INPUT -i $lan_interface -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $lan_interface -p icmp -j ACCEPT


    ########################## SERVER --- > INTERNET

    # DNS
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --dport 0:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p udp --dport 0:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p udp --sport 0:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    # http https
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 80 --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    # mail pop3
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 110 --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
    # mail smtp
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 25 --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
    # ftp
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 21 --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o -$internet_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 --dport 21 -j ACCEPT


    ############# VPN ------> INTERNET

    for vpn_interface in ${VPN_INTERFACES[@]}
    do

    # ICMP ping_vpn
    iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn_interface -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn_interface -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    # DNS for vpn
    iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn_interface -p tcp --dport 0:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn_interface -p udp --dport 0:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn_interface -p udp --sport 0:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    # forward vpn--->internet
    iptables -A FORWARD -i $vpn_interface -o $internet_interface -p ALL -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i $internet_interface -o $vpn_interface -p ALL -j ACCEPT

    # VPN -------- > SERVER

    # allow all for translocal connections
    iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn_interface -p tcp --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $vpn_interface -p udp --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $vpn_interface -p udp --sport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT

    done

    # LAN -------- > SERVER
    # allow all for local connections
    iptables -A INPUT -i $lan_interface -p tcp --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $lan_interface -p tcp --sport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $lan_interface -p udp --dport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $lan_interface -p udp --sport 0:65535 -j ACCEPT


    # LAN -------- > SERVER
    # VPN connection GRE-47 protocol accept
    iptables -A INPUT -i $lan_interface -p 47 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $lan_interface -p 47 -j ACCEPT


    # INTERNET ------------ > SERVER

    # incoming web
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp -m multiport --destination-port 80,443 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp -m multiport --source-port 80,443 -j ACCEPT
    # incoming mail pop3
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 110 -j ACCEPT
    # incoming mail smtp
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
    # incoming imap
    iptables -A INPUT -i $internet_interface -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internet_interface -p tcp --sport 143 -j ACCEPT


    stat_done
    ;;
  stop)
    stat_busy "Stopping Iptables Rules"

    iptables -F
    iptables -F -t nat
    iptables -F -t mangle

    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

    stat_done
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"  
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just switch from matching on interface names to using source IP addresses, use your PPP pool block as the source and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

use a wildcard, ie. ppp+ instead of ppp0, that will allow all ppp interfaces' traffic to pass through